# How to log a string and object at the same time in a Ruby controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am able to log things with things like

```
logger.debug "This is a logged string"
```

but when I try to do something like

```
logger.debug "This is the object: " + object_name
```

it doesn't like that and gives an error.  How do I concatinate the object into a string and output it together with whatever I want to label that debug line?

Thanks!

Comment: try using parentheses...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can probably do something like:

```
logger.debug "This is the object: #{object_name.inspect}"
```

Comment: yes that was it. StackOverflow says I can accept your answer in 10 min, and I'll do that then :)  need 15 karma points to upvote answers :)

Comment: Using string interpolation (with `inspect`) is more idiomatic.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Ruby's string interpolation.

```
logger.debug "This is the object: #{object_name}"
```